# Best brand-agnostic term for encounters?

Tags: terminology

I'm building myself a little tool for keeping track of campaign and adventure details, and I need a generic term for what D&D refers to as encounters. Something simple that can refer to combat, meetings with diplomats, traps, etc.

However, I don't want to pick a term that conflicts with established terms for other things. Are there any systems already using any of the following terms that might cause such a conflict?

1. Scene
2. Encounter
3. Scenario
4. Event

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! This question may be having a scope problem: the spectrum of RPGs [is inanely vast](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1475/4398), to the point that what D&D calls "encounters" is actually a very narrow slice of the sort of thing you're trying to define. Feel free to join the [chat] if you'd like to discuss it outside the confines of Stack guidelines, though.

Comment: doppelgreener, I see your point. Opinion doesn't really have a right or wrong answer. But I'm glad to know that the word "scene" is taken in Fate.

Comment: "Encounter" is in fact a very wide term and in D&D covered talking to market-stallholders, diplomatic wrangles, combat, consulting a sage, and basically anything that involves NPCs from outside the party. If you think about the term as an English word rather than gamer jargon, it is really quite general. "Scene" is a little more general, but it carries with it an implication of staging or visual media that may not suit your style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There likely isn't one. Proving a negative is hard, but the list of available words is small, [the amount of RPG systems numbers in the thousands](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/1204), and each RPG system is going to be using multiple such terms, and they're probably going to find their own separate usages for them.

(Fate for instance uses scene, scenario, *and* conflict, and to mean different things than other games might use them for, or for what you might use them for.)

There isn't going to be a 'best' term, so you have your arbitrary pick of decent terms. If you're building a system-agnostic tool, I suggest you accept the fact you're going to have language conflicts. Rather than try to be consistent with every single RPG (an unachievable goal), just create your own internal vocabulary for your tool and make sure it's *internally consistent.* People will be able to adapt and figure out that when you say 'scene' (or whatever you choose), you mean that other category of thing in their own game.

If you're building a system-specific tool, use that system's language. If you're making a tool that caters to a limited list of specific systems, of course, you have the option to allow people to pick the vocabulary for *that system.* Even a system-agnostic tool could offer this for a limited number of systems.

Comment: Based on this answer I did some research and found out scenarios are (more or less) a collection of scenes. I always thought they were interchangeable. Thanks for the info!